# What is the size of A given Ax=B

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix equation A$\vec{x}$ = B, where B = $\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\7\end{bmatrix}$, 
how many rows and columns does A have if:

$\vec{x}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ + s$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ + t$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

The thing that throws me off is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ where there is no coefficient in front of it. Because there is a missing coefficient, we cant assume A= $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & -1\\0 & 1& 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ right? Can someone explain how I would go about solving this. Would A be a 3x2 matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$A$ takes in a 3D vector and spits out a 3D vector, so $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. Since $s$ and $t$ do not affect the value of $Ax$, it must be the case that both $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ are in the kernel of $A$. You also know that $\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\7\end{pmatrix}$ is in the image.

Since you have 2 linearly independent vectors in the kernel and one in the image, you have complete information about $A$.